# Powershell: Working as script, but not as a module

Tags: powershell, module

I have written a simple code to connect the console to different clients and different services with two switch options

First: select the customer/client
Second: select the service (Azure AD/Ex Online)

When I run this as a script, it works without any issues.
When I run this as a module, it still works to the point that when I select Exchange Online, it will login with the saved credentials and "import" some data.

But for example `Get-Mailbox` is no recognized command - only if I run this as a script - though the "connection" to O365 is alive. In this step I have to redo the `Import-PSSession` again to get those commands working.

Can somebody tell me what I've done or understood wrong, here?

Thanks.

```
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Easy connect to different O365 Modules
    .DESCRIPTION
    Use the different options to connect to O365: AzureAD, Exchange Online, etc.
    .PARAMETER Client
    Enter the client you are trying to connect to.
    BUD (****)
    MEN (****)
    .PARAMETER Service
    Enter the service you need.
    Option 1: AAD (Azure AD)
    Option 2: Exchange (Exchange Online)
    .EXAMPLE
    Connect-O365 -Client BUD
    .NOTES
    Written by: Daniel Leiner
    Version:    1.2
    Date:       05/07/2019

#>

param(
[parameter(mandatory=$false)][string]$Client,
[parameter(mandatory=$false)][string]$Service
)

        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Client)) {

  $Client = switch (Read-Host "Hello, which client you want to connect to?" `n "1) BUD "`n "2) Men" `n "3) Different"`n)
{
        1 { "BUD"; break }
        2 { "MEN"; break }
        3 { "Unknown"; break }
        default { "Inkorrekte Eingabe" }

}
                                              }    
            If ($Client -eq "BUD")
                {$Cred = Get-StoredCredential -User admin@************}
        Elseif ($Client -eq "MEN")
                {$Cred = Get-StoredCredential -User admin@*************}
        Elseif ($Client -eq "Unknown")
                { $Cred = Get-Credential" }

      if ([string]::isNullorEmpty($Service)) {

 switch (Read-Host "Where do you want to connect to?" `n "a) AzureAD" `n "b) Exchange Online" `n)
                {
                    a { $service = "AAD"; break }
                    b { $service = "Exchange"; break }
                    default { "Incorrect Input." } 
                } 
                                            }

            if ($service -eq "AAD") 
            { Connect-AzureAD -Credential $cred }
        elseif ($service -eq "Exchange")
            { $global:worksession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -Credential $cred -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid `
            -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection 
        Import-PSSession $global:worksession -AllowClobber -DisableNameChecking
                        }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember to share your code. This way other people can take a look at it and maybe figure out what went wrong.

Comment: hello Mathyn, i've updated the question with my code.

Comment: How do you invoke it? It might be scope issue. It might not run the import for your current scope.

Comment: uhm what do you mean invoke? I uploaded it as psm1 into the modules folder and do an import-module by my profile script.

Comment: `If (Get-Module -Listavailable O365 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
 {
 Import-Module O365
 Write-Color "O365 Connect Module" -Color Yellow;Write-Color "is successfully loaded. Connect-O365 now usable for easier access. ``n"
}
Else { Write-Color "O365 Connect Module" -Color Yellow;Write-Color "Module does not exist. Cannot be loaded.``n" }`

Comment: You seem to have just taken a script and renamed it to a PSM1.  PowerShell will load it, but you should really wrap your code in functions and export them so the user can call them as needed.  Get some detials here: [How to Write a PowerShell Script module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-script-module)

Comment: Wait - i checked a lot of articles and they all said if you have a working script, you can also use it as a module. Where is the difference of making every single step in a function or just using one single function which has 2 switches and some code in it?

The user who is using that is me - i wrote it for myself as a time- and work-saver.

Comment: Even your article says this: Take an existing PowerShell script, and save the script with a .psm1 extension. @boxdog

Comment: @demji1985  Yes, but how do you propose to call your code and pass the parameters to it?  If you make no changes other than giving it a PSM1 extension, what have you gained that you didn't have when it was a PS1?

Comment: @boxdog sorry if I do not understand this - I am pretty newish to powershell and might miss some knowledge about this.

Comment: Ok i solved this myself by adding "Import-Module (" to the "Import-PSSession" line.